# Group by multiple columns at the same time

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, multiple-columns

I need to make a query to return the count of rows grouped by start date and end date at the same time :

Example :

```
              start date       end  date  
employee1 :   10/05/2015       12/05/2015  
employee2 :   11/05/2015       13/05/2015  
employee3 :   10/05/2015       12/05/2015  
employee4 :   11/05/2015       15/05/2015
```

query should return : 2(same start and end),1,1

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you tried anything yet? In the event that is a no, first open google and search linq "group by", "order by" and "then by". We are more than happy to help you if you have a valid question. What you have at the moment is a statement not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Emlpoyee> grouped= employees.GroupBy(o => new { o.Start, o.End });
```

It will group all employees by the start and end date. So all employees with the same start and end date will be in the same group.

Comment: Some explications should be useful

Comment: Well I think its pretty apparent given the question. But Ill add a note @GilleQ.

Comment: It's always better some explanation rather than just a code sample imo